# Scriptaculous Slide Toggle effect not working in IE6

Tags: scriptaculous, internet-explorer-6

I'm facing an issue with IE6 and a slide toggle effect by Scriptaculous. This is the script:

```
Event.observe(window, 'load', init, false);
function init() {
Effect.toggle('shipping_box','slide'); 
return false;   
}
```

It's working well with all browsers (included IE 7/8) but not in IE 6..and I don't know why..

Answer (score 0):

I solved. Issue concerned the dimensions of a png image included in the sliding div.

IE6 uses a 'fix png' script in this site and needs dimensions in order to work.

I didn't give them to image and thus nothing appeared.